# Call functions asynchronous without change the function

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I created an example to show you what my problem is. I will post the code, then explain.

My JS:

```
$('#mybtn').on('click', function(){
//$(fn1).promise().done(fn2);
$.Deferred(fn1).then(fn2);
});

function fn1(){
    console.log("1");
            $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                func: "1"
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
}

function fn2(){
    console.log("2");
            $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                func: "2"
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
}
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
$request = $_POST['func'];

    switch ($request) {
        case '1':
            fn1();
            break;
        case '2':
            fn2();
            break;                  
    }

    function fn1(){
        print "1";
        sleep(4);
    }

    function fn2(){
        print "2";  
        sleep(2);
    }

?>
```

So, i tried with those 2 ways to call the functions and wait for them to end, the first : //$(fn1).promise().done(fn2); prints 1, 2 then 2, 1. The Second: $.Deferred(fn1).then(fn2); prints 1, 1 and stop, just don't even call the fn2, what i want to print is 1, 1, 2, 2. I can resolve the problem returning the ajax request in a variable then just use promise().done but i can't do that, i need to wait the function without change it, is that possible? I mean like this:

```
    toWait.someWayToWait().then(anotherFunctionToWait());

    function toWait(){
        //whatever code or functions in here.
        fn1();
        fn2();
        fnX();
    }

function anotherFunctionToWait(){
    //whatever code or functions in here.
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Can't pass in a callback to each function?

Comment: @tymeJV I guess didn't understand, what you mean exactly?

Comment: such as `function fn1(callback)` then reference the callback function in the success

Comment: @tymeJV how can i add a callback to each function? '-' and i guess it will not wait for the functions inside them to end...

Comment: @tymeJV hmmm thinking...

Answer (score 0):

No. Since the functions provide no way for the caller to know when it has completed, you cannot wait for them to be done. You'd need to change the function somehow.

<sup>Strictly speaking, it could be accomplished with monkeypatching, but that is a horrible way to do it.</sup>